# No module named LBPHFacerecognizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

python version 3.6.1
numpy version 1.13.1
OpenCV version 3.3.0

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image

recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
path = 'dataset'

def getImageWithID(path):
imagesPaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
faces = []
IDs = []
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    faceImg = Image.open(imagePath)
    faceNp = np.array(faceImg, 'uint8')
    ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
    faces.append(faceNp)
    IDs.append(ID)
    cv2.imshow("training the data ", facesNp)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
return IDs, faces

Ids, faces = getImageWithID(path)       
recognizer.train(faces, Ids)
recognizer.save("recognizer/trainingData.yml")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer
'

Comment: Try cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using Opencv 3.x. Try `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` for the said problem.

But if still compatibility issue persists then either add opencv_contrib module to your existing opencv 3.x version or change the opencv to older version.

Comment: cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() didn't worked , it would be very helpful if you can tell me to which version should i downgrade opencv to ?         opencv_contrib is installed already .